# Django template not displaying data from database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am running into an issue where my database is information is displaying on one template, but I want certain parts to display on another page for a blog.

When I click into physics-blog it will display my images and post title. For this, I have looped through the database. Works fine and perfectly.

But when I click into one of them and want to show {{ physicsBlog.body }} it doesn't show anything. Which I can't wrap my head around because that works just fine in the other ListView template, but not in the DetailView template.

Here is my code.

models.py

```py
class physicsBlog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    blog_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)
```

views.py

```py
class physicsBlogListView(ListView):
    model = physicsBlog
    template_name = 'physics.html'
    ordering = ['-id']

class physicsBlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = physicsBlog
    template_name = 'physics-blog-details.html'
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('physics-blog', physicsBlogListView.as_view(), name="physics-blog"),
    path('physics-blog/<int:pk>', physicsBlogDetailView.as_view(), name="physics-blog-details"),
    path('crypto-blog', cryptoBlogListView.as_view(), name="crypto-blog"),
    path('crypto-blog/<int:pk>', cryptoBlogDetailView.as_view(), name="crypto-blog-details"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar using these generic displays that Django provides, but from the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView) it says

> While this view is executing, self.object will contain the object that
> the view is operating upon.

So maybe try `{{ object.body }}` in your template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard way of rendering data in standard single-object view (mostly DetailView):

```
{{ object.body }}
```

But if you want to see it better, just add `context_object_name` variable:

```
class physicsBlogDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = "physics_blog"
    ...
```

After such change in template:

```
{{ physics_blog.body }}
```

Without `context_object_name` it's `object` or `object_list`. I'm kinda surprised that you did ok in ListView and had problem in DetailView, because it's the same thing.